# Comparing SQL Result and data from xlsx file

Tags: python, sql-server, excel

I am trying to compare data from excel file and result from SQL Query, when I try to print the result they are the same but when I use For and If its showing that the data are not the same.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
xlsx = pd.read_excel(r'SrcExcelFile.xlsx')
out = xlsx.to_numpy().tolist()
out1 = [tuple(elt) for elt in out]

conn_str = (r'connection')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
with open(r'Target_1.sql') as Q1:
ReadTargetFile2 = Q1.read()
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
SQL_QUERY = cursor.execute(ReadTargetFile2)
sqlResult = cursor.fetchall()

print(out1)
print(sqlResult)

print(type(out1))
print(type(sqlResult))

for rctest in sqlResult :
 if rctest in out1:
  print('%s is in SRC' % rctest[0])
 else:
  print('%s is not in SRC' % rctest[0])
exit()


Result
[('Test1', 'Y'), ('Test2', 'Y'), ('Test3', 'Y')]
[('Test1', 'Y'), ('Test2', 'Y'), ('Test3', 'Y')]

<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>

Test1 is not in SRC
Test2 is not in SRC
Test3 is not in SRC`
```

I am expecting that the result will match

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. It's not clear where blocks of code end.

Comment: the else is on the same level as for. Although, i can't reproduce your problem even after fixing that. I'm guessing tuples aren't really tuples or there's something else going on with datatypes between the two different lists. you could print the element class to see if something weird is up perhaps

Comment: my apologies for the indentation, i edited the code and include the class for xlsx and sqlResult

Comment: Have you tried different encodings on pd.read()?

Comment: not yet I'm new to python sorry, will very much appreciate all the suggestion thank you but ill also try to search and test all the different encodings i can find. thank you